# Invalid pagetoken with Google API - Status 400

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

While accessing Google Chrome connector API, at some point i am getting an error saying "Invalid input with the pageToken Status 400"

No API limit exceeds. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Any idea what ended up causing this error for you?